# Multiplication of a numeric array and a symbolic array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following code:

```
a=zeros(1,3);
syms x
y=zeros(1,3);
for j = 1:3
    a = [zeros(1,j-1) 1 zeros(1,3-j)];
    y(1,j)=x*a(1,j);
    display(y(1,j));
end;
```

which I want to give me an array like `[0 x 0]` for each iteration. But, on contrary, it gives me the following error:

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in 
Untitled123 (line 6)
y(1,j)=x*a(1,j);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you allocated `y` as a numeric (floating-point) array, not a symbolic one. `a` is numeric, but when you multiply it by `x` the result becomes symbolic. Because `x` is a symbolic variable rather than a symbolic value, Matlab cannot perform the automatic cast back to double precision. You can allocate `y` like this:

```
y = sym(zeros(1,3));
```

Comment: Sorry pal,But the hint which you have provided above, could not solve my problem.As i said,I want to have an array like [0 x 0],in which x is symbolic variable in each iteration,for example,in first iteration [x 0 0],in second iteration [0 x 0],and in third iteration,[0 0 x]...

Comment: @MRMeyqani: Yes it can. This is the allocation of `y` (your third line of code), not the part in the `for` loop. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: Ok,I got it.
Do you have any suggestions for the loop part?

Comment: The entirety of your code is equivalent to: `syms x;` `y = x+zeros(1,3);`, so I'm not sure what all of the intermediate steps are.

Comment: Ok Andy.
I'm trying to code the Cyclic Coordinate Method.This is one of the algorithms which are used for Optimization.in one the algorithm's steps,you need to minimize f(y(1,i)+x*d(1,j)),where x belongs to R.I'm told to do this minimization with Newton's Method.So I need to    differentiate f with regard to x,and I don't want to differentiate numerically!in the function which I've mentioned above,y(1,j) and d(1,j) are numerical vectors,where jth element of d(1,j) is 1 and other elements are zero.
Now,Can You help me with this?